# How to create a user that can only manage the dashboards in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is there anyway to create a user that can only do the CRUD operations on dashboards in kibana?i need this kind of permission but i cant figure out how to create it.
Can someone help?

Comment: What do you mean by CRUD? Creating, Reading, Updating, and Deleting of Dashboards? Visualizations?

Comment: this is the first time iam using ELK. so both exactly, i need a user to just create ,update ,read ,delete the dashboards and also add the visualizations to them. but i dont know which permissions to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the recent versions it´s pretty easy as you can use kibana to manage the roles and kibana features per space and role.

Have a closer look at [kibana role management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.9/kibana-role-management.html) and [kibana privileges](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.9/kibana-privileges.html) - I´ts pretty well documented!

Comment: i did that! but when i login with user and click dashboard, it gives me this message: "In order to visualize and explore data in kibana, you'll need to create an index pattern to retrive data from elastic search." i already have some index patterns. so i decided to ask it.looks like there is something  missing.

Comment: problem solved.i created the index pattern in my own space.